# Show that the given collection S of subsets of the set X is a partition of X.

Tags: abstract-algebra

I feel as if I'm going in circles with this proof.

[image]

[image]

Comment: Okay. What have you tried?

Comment: for (i) Let (a,b) be in X. Therefore (a,b) are in Z+. which means that gcd(a,b) is in Sn. Thus union of all Sn=X.

Comment: for(ii)Proof by contradiction: Assume Sn intersect Sn1 is empty. Therefore gcd(a,b)=gcd(a1,b1) implies n=n1. thus contradiction.

Comment: Your proof is ok.

Comment: are you sure. My professor says I'm wrong?

Answer (score 2):

Since I've offered a bounty and my reputation fell below 50, I'll simply leave a hint here instead of commenting, sorry!

Hint: a family is a partition iff it is a family of abstraction classes of a certain equivalence relation. And (under axiom of choice) Relation $R$ is equivalence iff there exists $f$ such that $aRb$ iff $f(a)=f(b)$. The formulation of a task involves a certain promising $f:Z^+ \times Z^+ \rightarrow Z^+$...